# Clustering Circular area with different angles

Tags: algorithm, random, cluster-analysis, distance

Let's say that I have a circular area and n objects deployed randomly in this area. I want to divide the circle into K groups from position of center such that objects in same area treated as member of same group. Moreover, K person assigned to visit K groups from the position of circle center (Specifically, one person for one group). Now, I want to group such a way that, traveling distance of a person for each group close to each other.

If objects are deployed uniformly, it's very easy. Only divide the area into equal angles gives me the desired results. But, for random deployment of objects, I could not divide the circular area (specifically, could not fix the angle) which gives me traveling distance for each person in each group which is close to each other

Comment: How is travel distance defined? As the distance of the shortest path that connects all objects of a group and the circle center? That alone is an NP-hard problem (travelling salesman)

Comment: Yes.distance of shortest path that connects all objects of a group and circle center.Using any well known heuristic, traveling distance can be obtained. But how divide group  such that traveling distance for each group close to each other when deployment is random.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the subproblem of finding the shortest path within a group is NP-hard. Hence, the overall problem is NP-hard. I will present a dynamic programming algorithm that can either solve the problem exactly (in exponential time) or approximate it with a heuristic (in polynomial time).

Both variants require a function `f(g)` that evaluates the travel distance of a group. In the exact variant, you need to solve TSP. In the approximate variant, you use a heuristic. You should try several heuristics and see which one fits best. For example, the area of the objects' bounding ring might be a good start (plus the distance of the closest object to the center).

The actual algorithm looks as follows: Calculate the angular position of each object and sort them with respect to this position. Also, calculate the distance to the center.

For now, we assume that the first group starts at the first object. Then, we want to find the grouping that minimizes the sum of `f(g)` over all groups. The states of the dynamic program are parameterized by the number of groups specified so far and by the object that belongs to the first next group. This makes a 2D table. You can easily initialize the first column by calculating `f()` for the resulting group:

```
       groups | 1           2  3  4  5  6 ... K
next object   |
--------------+------------------------
   o2         | f(o1->o1)
   o3         | f(o1->o2)
   ...        | ...
   on         | f(o1->on-1)
   o1         | f(o1->on)
```

Then, you fill the subsequent columns. For each entry, you have to compare the group to all groups in the previous column and find the one with the minimum sum:

```
entry(column i, object j) = min_k (entry(i - 1, k) + f(ok->j-1))
```

Actually, you don't have to calculate the entire column. You can leave entries at the beginning and end empty if they do not allow to fit in `K` groups. E.g. in the first column, you only need to calculate up to `on-(K-1)` because you have to leave `K-1` objects unassigned in order to get a valid grouping. You may cache the results of `f` to avoid duplicate calculations.

After you filled the table, you're interested in `entry(K, o1)`. Follow the path from this entry back to the start and you get the optimal grouping where the first group starts at `o1`. Do this for the first `n-K` objects as group starts and you get the overall optimum.

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^3 * K * T(f))` where `T(f)` is the complexity of calculating `f(g)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nico.Actually,i am not so clear about your solution.can you explain more?I want to fix the angle for each group also. How can i fix the angle from your algorithm?If you explain more,it helps me much...

Comment: If you mean that you know the angles of the sectors, then this requires a different approach (because you have only one continuous-valued degree of freedom instead of several discrete-valued). About what parts are you having questions?

Comment: Actually,i want to distribute angle among each group such that every group contains the objects that visit a person from center to every group,and distance of person for every group close to each other.Suppose,I have K groups and divide the circle (360/K) angels.Now i want to adjust angel of K groups such that traveling distance of each group nearly equal...

Comment: Then you just need to adjust the objective function. Use variance or standard deviation instead of `entry(i - 1, k) + f(ok->j-1)`. However, time complexity will increase. Have you tried a simple approach like k-means?

Comment: yes.I tried k means.Its not gave the balance distance for every group because deployment is random.